# Django no guarda un form usando ORM

Tags: python, validación, django-forms

Tengo un campo llamado medicamento en mi modelo que es una clave foranea de otro. Quiero que muestre todos los medicamentos en un combobox que se permita buscar también. El widget de busqueda y selección  que encontré con Floppyforms funciono OK pero cuando envio el submit obtengo el error: "Escoja una opción válida. Esa opción no está entre las disponibles." Espero me puedan ayudar con esto.

models.py

```
class Stockmov(models.Model):
numero = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Fecha de Movimiento")
author = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name="autor",on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
medicamento= models.ForeignKey(Medicamento,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
motivo= models.CharField(max_length=200)
Cantidad = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
class StockmovForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Stockmov

    fields =  ['medicamento', 'motivo', 'Cantidad' ]
    widgets = {
    #'medicamento': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Medicamento'}),
    'medicamento': forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Medicamento'},datalist=Medicamento.objects.all()), 
    'motivo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Motivo'}),
    'Cantidad': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Cantidad'}),
    }
    labels = {
        'medicamento':'Medicamento', 'motivo':'Motivo del Movimiento', 'Cantidad':'Cantidad del Movimiento',
    }
```

views.py

```
class StockmovCreate(CreateView):
model = Stockmov
form_class = StockmovForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('stockmov:stockmov')

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    print(self.request.user)
    return super(StockmovCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Template

```
      <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}`s`
        <div class="text-center">
          <input type="submit" id="btnCrear" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" value="Crear Movimiento" />
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución alternativa que econtre fue quitar floppyforms y utilizar Select2 en cambio. Este soporta busquedas por el campo del foreign key y tambien permiete crear una instancia facilmente desde el CreateView.

Template

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_medicamento').select2();
});
</script>
```

forms.py

```
class StockmovForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = Stockmov

fields =  ['medicamento', 'motivo', 'Cantidad' ]
widgets = {
'medicamento': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control', 
 'placeholder':'Medicamento'}),
'motivo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Motivo'}),
'Cantidad': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 
'placeholder':'Cantidad'}), 
 }
labels = {
  'medicamento':'Medicamento', 'motivo':'Motivo del Movimiento', 
'Cantidad':'Cantidad del Movimiento',
 }
```